# React from NPM cannot be used on the client because 'development' is not defined. The bundle was generated from Webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, reactjs, webpack

I'm creating a React Node.js app and I'm trying to generate a Webpack bundle containing the React source code I loaded from NPM.

However, it seems that the React code from NPM cannot be used directly in the client. It triggers this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: development is not defined
```

The code that triggers the exception is from the React code:

[image: sample]

Is there anything I can do to make that work?

**EDIT**

This is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import yargs from 'yargs';
import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin';

export default {
    entry: {
        bundle: './src/client.js'
    },

    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: './dist/assets',
        publicPath: '/assets/'
    },

    externals: undefined,

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.json']
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.js/, loader: 'babel?optional=es7.objectRestSpread!client', exclude: /node_modules/ },
            {test: /\.css/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader")},
            {test: /\.less$/, loader:  ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader!less-loader")},
            {test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json'},
            {test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$/, loader: 'file?name=[name].[ext]'},
            {test: /\.eot$|\.ttf$|\.svg$|\.woff2?$/, loader: 'file?name=[name].[ext]'}
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                'NODE_ENV': 'development'
            },
            'development': true
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css')
    ]
};
```

My `client.js` file only contains this line (for the purpose of debugging this issue):

```
import React from 'react';
```

[And here is the resulting bundle](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/andrerpena/42b955fe2689ffab41ef/raw/c3ac25b9329f293042b4eb5c98f0890d080be184/gistfile1.txt)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Any values passed to `webpack.DefinePlugin` as strings are treated as code fragments—that is to say, using

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  ENV: "development"
});
```

with the code

```
console.log(ENV);
```

results in

```
console.log(development);
```

Instead, you want

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  ENV: "\"development\""
});
```

which will result in

```
console.log("development");
```

---

To fix your issue, change your plugins to

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
            'NODE_ENV': "'development'"
        }
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css')
]
```

I usually allow webpack to read from `process.env.NODE_ENV` so that React minifies properly when you run webpack with `NODE_ENV=production`:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  "process.env": { NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || "development") }
})
```

Comment: thanks for the answer and for the `stringify` tip. I didn't know that. I think I don't need this, though, because the `development` variable is boolean. It's also interesting that I can't find the declaration of `development` anywhere in the output file after using the `DefinePlugin`. Anyway, I edited the question to include my webpack.config file. Thank you.

Comment: Here's the resulting bundle, if you are interested: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/andrerpena/42b955fe2689ffab41ef/raw/c3ac25b9329f293042b4eb5c98f0890d080be184/gistfile1.txt

Comment: @andrerpena You're getting `development` in your bundle because you set `'NODE_ENV': 'development'` which sets any `process.env.NODE_ENV` to *LITERALLY* `development` (not a string, just the literal) instead of `"development"` (a string, like you want). You should stringify the value (e.g. just use `'NODE_ENV': "'development'"`) so that webpack inserts a *string* instead any time it sees `process.env.NODE_ENV`. Re-defining `development` with webpack isn't doing anything because it's only showing up because of the first misconfiguration.

Comment: How the heck didn't I see that? I copied this piece of code from somewhere else. Actually react should look at `process.env.NODE_ENV` then and use it, that's why there's a lot of `development` literals in my output bundle. I removed completely the `DefinePlugin` and now it seems to be working fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: @andrerpena webpack doesn't inherit `process.env.NODE_ENV` by default, you do have to set up a `DefinePlugin` for it. Things work fine it development without it (because `"production" !== undefined` is true), but if you want to produce a faster React bundle for `NODE_ENV=production` builds, it will be required to allow uglify to optimize it out.

Comment: **Webpack 4 Update** - If you're on Webpack 4 and have a `mode` set, you should simply remove/exclude `webpack.DefinePlugin` since [webpack will now handle](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/#specify-the-mode) `process.env.NODE_ENV` by default.